# Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError on another domain

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The number of the problem related questions is huge. I spent a lot of time and probably took a look on each of them, however I haven’t found a solution for my case.

There is a domain (let's call it **domain.com**). Google maps is connected to it with the key for years: `<script src="//google.com/jsapi?key=the_key_is_here"></script>`

There is a new domain (let's call it **domain-new.com**) - the full clone of the first domain. But the Google Map doesn't work on it and there is an error in the console: `Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError`.

What methods of solution have I tried:

1. Creating a new key
2. Include all Google Maps APIs in *console.cloud.google.com*
3. Specify all possible referrers in *console.cloud.google.com*:

   - `domain.com`
   - `*.domain.com/*`
   - `domain.com/contact`
   - `domain-new.com`
   - `*.domain-new.com/*`
   - `domain-new.com/contact`
4. Specifying the versions of the included script (`?v=3`/`?v=3.exp`/`?v=3.26`)
5. Replace the included script with: `<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=the_key_is_here"></script>`

All the changes were made simultaneously for **domain.com** and **domain-new.com**. The map worked successfully on **domain.com**, but there still was an error on **domain-new.com**.

Therefore, the exactly same map with the same key works on **domain.com** at the moment, but nevertheless it doesn't work on **domain-new.com**. All relevant documentation for the Google Maps API was read and no suitable solutions have been found. In conclusion, I hope your will help me.

Comment: 1) Did you try generating a new key? 2) Did you try removing all referrers? When you do, does it work? The `MissingKeyMapError` you mentioned suggests that the API is called without the `key` parameter. Did you make sure on domain-new.com that the call to the API is made with that key (look at the network tab in the developer tools and find the call to the API)? Btw. this is not really the place for this kind of questions as it doesn't really involve programming...

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks for the comment.

1. I pointed out explicitly those methods I tried in the question. The first point is just creation of a new key - it didn’t help.
2. Yes, I tried to delete all refferers, thereby removing the usage restriction on the specific domains. This didn’t change anything.

Yes, the API call occurs with the specified key, I even tried to debug Google jsapi gradually, but the script is too big and complicated, so it's ineffectual.

Comment: Then I would try the [product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/maps) and give all details there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.